# combining two multilevel indices into a single datetime stamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have following dataframe with multilevel index. Here first index is the date of the year and second index is the half-hourly time.

```
Date             
2010-07-01  00:00    1.250
            00:30    1.244
            01:00    1.256
            01:30    0.744
            02:00    0.019
            02:30    1.250
            03:00    0.069
            03:30    0.000
            04:00    0.000
```

I want to combine the two indexes together into a single timestamp like following:

```
Date             
 2010-07-01 00:00    1.250
 2010-07-01 00:30    1.244
 2010-07-01 01:00    1.256
 2010-07-01 01:30    0.744
 2010-07-01 02:00    0.019
 2010-07-01 02:30    1.250
 2010-07-01 03:00    0.069
 2010-07-01 03:30    0.000
 2010-07-01 04:00    0.000
```

I tried following code:

```
import datetime as dt

dat=df1.index.get_level_values(0)[0]
stamp=df1.index.get_level_values(1)[0]

indx=[dt.datetime(dat,stamp) for dat,stamp in zip(*[df.index.get_level_values(i) for i in (0, 1)])]
```

However I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the dtypes of your index levels?  Are the 'O' (ie. strings)?

Comment: first index is Timestamp and second is string

Comment: My heuristic solution: `indx=[dt.datetime(dat,stamp) ...` => `indx=[dt.datetime(dat,int(stamp)) ...` (`int()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert time strings:

```
dat=df1.index.get_level_values(0)
stamp=df1.index.get_level_values(1)
df1.index = dat + pd.to_timedelta(stamp + ':00')
print (df1.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2010-07-01 00:00:00', '2010-07-01 00:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 01:00:00', '2010-07-01 01:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 02:00:00', '2010-07-01 02:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 03:00:00', '2010-07-01 03:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 04:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='30T')
```

Another solution with `map`:

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index.map(lambda x: '{} {}'.format(x[0], x[1])))
print (df1.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2010-07-01 00:00:00', '2010-07-01 00:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 01:00:00', '2010-07-01 01:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 02:00:00', '2010-07-01 02:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 03:00:00', '2010-07-01 03:30:00',
               '2010-07-01 04:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```